# ExpressionEngine -> Template inclusion(s)

Tags: templates, expressionengine

ExpressionEngine template code:

```
<div class="container_16">
  <div class="grid_16">
{if "{segment_1}" == "home"}
  {embed="include/title" title="welcome"}
{if:elseif "{segment_1}" == "login"}
  {embed="include/title" title="login"}
{if:else}
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    if($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
?>
      {embed="include/title" title="welcome"}
<?php
    } else {            
?>    
      {embed="include/title" title="login"}
<?php 
    }
  }
?>          
{/if}
  </div> <!-- grid_16 -->
</div> <!-- container_16 -->
```

The problem I'm having with the code above is that when segment_1 is empty,
I want it to show the title template with the embed title=login only if the 
$_SESSION['loggedin'] is not true.

I *KNOW* that the session variable is not even set so it should show the title 
template with login but it is not showing anything except this:

```
<div class="container_16">
  <div class="grid_16">

  </div> <!-- grid_16 -->
</div> <!-- container_16 -->
```

If I have home as segment_1, it shows the title template with the embed title=welcome.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use {logged_in} and {logged_out} variables?

Either way add additional conditionals:

```
{if "{segment_1}" == "home"}
  {embed="include/title" title="welcome"}
{if:elseif "{segment_1}" == "login" && logged_out}
  {embed="include/title" title="login"}
{if:else}
  {if logged_in}
    {embed="include/title" title="welcome"}
  {if:else}
    {embed="include/title" title="login"}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

In older versions of EE I've had issues with the if:else not working on the logged_in conditional, so you may just need to replace with:

```
{if logged_in}
{/if}
{if logged_out}
{/if}
```

If you have to use your session variable, ensure PHP is turned on in the template, and parsing is set to before EE. And you'd need to change the conditional slightly:

```
{if:elseif "{segment_1}" == "login" && "0" == "<?= (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) ? "1" : "0"; ?>"}
```

Although you might be able to get away with this (you'd need to test to confirm):

```
... && <?= (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) ? true : false; ?>}
```

Comment: [quote]Can you not use {logged_in} and {logged_out} variables?[/quote] No, we aren't using EE's membership routines.

Comment: I added some edits to the original post to cover your scenario of the PHP session variable. If you wanted to remove PHP completely from your template, you could use the session plugin (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/session-variables-plugin) to get the value.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the session variables plugin. will check the code later today.

Comment: Can't set parsing to before EE, causes problems. If set to Output, I get this error: <p>Message:  Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if:elseif "" == "login" || "0" == "<?= (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) ? "1" : "0"; ?>"}</p>

Comment: "causes problems" - some more details here would help.
try removing the double quotes in the PHP: {if:elseif "" == "login" || "0" == "<?= (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) ? '1' : '0'; ?>"}